# numpy weighted average for calculating weighted mean squared error

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I am trying to compute weighted mean squared error for my regression problem. I have y_true, y_predicted, and y_wts numpy arrays. Each array is shaped (N,1) where N is the number of samples. I don't understand why the following 2 pieces of code give different answers:

1st code segment

```
import numpy as np
sq_error = (y_true-y_predicted)**2
wtd_sq_error = np.multiply(sq_error,y_wts)
wtd_mse = np.mean(wtd_sq_error)
```

2nd code segment taken from sklearn metrics [mean_squared_error function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/metrics/regression.py#L183)

```
wtd_mse_sklearn = np.average((y_true - y_predicted)**2, axis =0,
                               weights=y_wts)
```

I came to test this owing to mis-match between tensorflow weighted mean squared error and sklearn metrics mean squared error (with weight column specified). Note that this mismatch doesnt occur when I don't specify a weight column.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Because you forgot about weight:

```
np.mean = sum(error_i * weight_i ∀ i) / len(error_i ∀ i)
```

while

```
np.average = sum(error_i * weight_i ∀ i) / sum(weight_i ∀ i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having the formula for the weighted average in your 1st code segment wrong, it should be:

```
wtd_mse = np.sum(sq_error * y_wts) / np.sum(y_wts)
```

instead of:

```
wtd_mse = np.mean(wtd_sq_error)
```